# Extract string between string regex busybox

Tags: shell-script, shell

I am trying to extract a string from between 2 strings using regex on BusyBox. I have been able to do it locally with

```
extract_string=$(echo $content | grep -P '(?<=CURRENT_VERSION ")(.*)(?=")' -o)
```

But sadly this BusyBox version of `grep` command does not support the `-P` option. I can use `sed`, `awk` and `grep`.

String: `#define CURRENT_VERSION "1.0.0.2" some other random text`

Output: `1.0.0.2`

Does anybody know another way I can achieve this?

**OS:** Kernel 2.6.x

**Utilities:** From busybox 1.2x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
extract_string=$(
  printf '%s\n' "$content" |
    sed -n 's/.*CURRENT_VERSION "\([^"]*\).*/\1/p'
)
```

With `awk`:

```
extract_string=$(
  printf '%s\n' "$content" |
    awk -F'"' '/CURRENT_VERSION/{ print $2 }'
)
```

Comment: Using `.*` in front pushes the match to the last `CURRENT_VERSION`, not the first as the OP regex does. Also the OP regex will match everything `.*\"` up to the last `"` not the same as `[^"]*`.

Answer (score 2):

Since the text to be extracted is inside a variable it is a real waste of processing time to call an external command like sed, awk or cut.

An equivalent regex could be used in several shells (ksh, bash, zsh):

```
re='CURRENT_VERSION "(.*)".*'
[[ $content =~ $re ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

If your shell doesn't have such capacity, use:

```
out1=${content#*\"}; out2=${out1%\"*}
[[ ${content} -ne ${#out1} ]] && 
    [[ ${#out1} -ne ${#out2} ]] &&
        echo "$out2"
```

The final tests ensure that both `"` generated a change in the string, and only then, the extracted string is printed.

Which will output the text between the first `"` and the last `"`.

Comment: Pattern matching works fine in the busybox shell, e.g. `${content##*'CURRENT_VERSION "'}` to stick with the OP's condition. However it completely lacks error checking, if it doesn't match then it will return the whole content string instead (whereas `grep` would return empty string and set error exit code). So it might be good to verify the string was shortened or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `cut` and `awk`

content='#define CURRENT_VERSION "1.0.0.2" some other random text'

`cut:`

```
extract_string=$(echo $content|cut -d '"' -f2)
```

`awk:`

```
extract_string=$(echo $content|awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/CURRENT_VERSION/)print $(i+1)}')
```